# Insert a Newline in Excel Formula (MacOS)

Tags: excel, newline, macos, formulas

I am using MS Excel on a Mac.

I have a formula, and I wish to insert a newline into it:

```
Guests!A1 & " " & Guests!B1 & [newline here] Guests!C1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You should add an "r" to the "macos" tag

Comment: I was about to remove the tag, then I realised it is for "MacOS" not "macros".

Answer (score 15):

CHAR() is the appropriate function for an Excel formula, and you need character 10 (Line Feed) to create a line break. Example:

```
Guests!A1 & " " & Guests!B1 & CHAR(10) & Guests!C1
```

You'll need to have word-wrapping enabled on the cell, otherwise CHAR(10) will just look like a little square.

vbCRLF would be the right choice when using VBA (i.e., a macro). The question is about formulas, not VBA.

Comment: Mac OS Excel is still stuck in the days of when Classic Macs used CR for newline. You'll find that `CHAR(13)` is the one you want, and it's not portable between Mac & PC. You may be able to build an OS-sniffing function with IF and INFO("OSVERSION").

Comment: Note that enabling Wrap Text is necessary to see these characters: https://superuser.com/questions/918520/how-to-add-a-line-break-to-the-output-of-a-formula-in-excel#comment1238383_918601

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: with the cursor in the formula bar, not directly in the text of the cell

Answer (score 0):

```
=Guests!A1 & " " & Guests!B1 & "<press Alt+Enter>  
" & Guests!C1
```

Replace `<press Alt+Enter>` by the actual key combination.
On a Mac, as Coxymla suggested, you will maybe replace Alt with another key ?

Comment: That trick only works for straight text. If you have a formula it does add a separate line in the formula bar, but that will not translate to the cell formatting. richardtallent's suggesting of char(10) is the way to go.